# How to apply tf.map_fn for each channel in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I need to apply smth like tf.map_fn to each channel for a batch of imgs
(512, 32, 32, 3)
where the last dim corresponds to a channel (rgb)
e.g

```
x = tf.map_fn(lambda channel: func(y), x)
```

where `func(y)` is a function applied to each channel-matrix e.g (512, 32, 32)

Is there some way of doing it?

Or maybe I can do smth like this

```
for ch in range(3):
   cp = tf.copy(x[:,:,:,ch])   #TF does not have copy, it's just pseudo code
   cp = tf.reshape(xp, [xp.shape[0], -1])
   out = func(cp)
   unsq = tf.reshape(out, [x.shape[0], 32, 32])
   [:,:,:,ch] = unsq
```

e.g I need to apply func over flattened images for each channel.
I am completely to tf so I have no idea how to accomplish it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just transpose the dimensions before calling `map_fn`:

```
x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[3,0,1,2]) # shape 3, 512, 32, 32
x = tf.map_fn(lambda channel: func(y), x)
```